# How can we drop a database in android?

Tags: android, database

How can we drop a database in android?

Comment: Try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#deleteDatabase%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "name_of_table";

try {
  db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
  db.execSQL("VACUUM");
} catch (SQLException sqle) {....}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a very late reply to this post, but if anyone else is facing the same issue, can try the following.

```
myContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
```